# Query syntax is checked at java level or Database Level?

Tags: mysql, java

If i used normal JDBC Connection for accessing database of Mysql, The syntax of query is checked at java level or Mysql level.

Example

`String Query="Select * fromEMP"`

above wrong query syntax throw a SQLException.

so this exception is actually thrown by MySQL or java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the java api (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) It would look to me that the exeption which is beeing thrown comes from the database.

From the Java API SQLException Constructors section

> SQLException()
>
> Constructs a SQLException object.
>
> SQLException(String reason)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason.
>
> SQLException(String reason, String SQLState)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason and SQLState.
>
> SQLException(String reason, String SQLState, int vendorCode)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason, SQLState and vendorCode.
>
> SQLException(String reason, String sqlState, int vendorCode, Throwable cause)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason, SQLState, vendorCode and cause.
>
> SQLException(String reason, String sqlState, Throwable cause)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason, SQLState and cause.
>
> SQLException(String reason, Throwable cause)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given reason and cause.
>
> SQLException(Throwable cause)
>
> Constructs a SQLException object with a given cause.

However the simple way to test this theory would be to use a second language e.g. PHP to attempt to run the same query, and see if you get the same message, if the execption is just coming from Java then you will get a diffrent message, if it is coming from the SQL connection i.e. the database its self then logic would state that you should have the same message return.

Answer (score 0):

Two different things probably:

- Syntax is checked in MySQL server. There may be connectors/client libraries which would do the parsing and checking before sending it, but it would only mean doing the same work twice. MySQL server receives query as string and then processes it. Even for prepared statements server receives statement as text and compiles it.
- SQLException is probably extended Java Exception, which is purely Java side construct (generally as part of JDBC code). So this exception is thrown by Java MySQL client library when it sends your query and instead of data, server returns some error message. Client and server communicate by socket or tcp, so there is no way how server could throw exception directly to client. It has to signalize error by some other means (probably different response packet type or something similar)